# Likelihood for a bayesian approach

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

We assume that $y_1,...,y_n$ are outcomes of iid. random variables $Y_1,...,Y_n$ with $Y_i \sim poiss(\lambda)$ Now we consider a Bayesian approach. I have to write up the likelihood and show that $\bar{y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum y_i$ is
sucient for $\lambda$ , i.e. that the likelihood only depends on $y_1,...,y_n$ through $\bar{y}$. But I'm not sure how to find the likelihood in that case? Can anyone help me? I know in order to find $\bar{y}$ we find the score function and isolate $y$ but how du I find the likelihood?

Comment: Seems like you are not concerned with Bayesian inference but the likelihood alone, isn't it?

Comment: The likelihood of $\bar{y}$ is just its probability mass function.  Since $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \sim Poisson(n\lambda)$, we can calculate the pmf of $\bar{y}$ by mapping values from $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ to $\bar{y}$.  In this case it is easy to show that the mapping is one-to-one, with $Pr[\bar{y} = k/n] = Pr\left[\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i = k\right] = \frac{(n\lambda)^k e^{-n\lambda}}{k!}$, for $k \in \{0, 1, \cdots\}$.  In fact, one usually works with $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ since it is also a complete sufficient statistic